# How to use Google Guice to create objects that require parameters?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Maybe I am just blind, but I do not see how to use Guice (just starting with it) to replace the `new` call in this method:

```
public boolean myMethod(String anInputValue) {
    Processor proc = new ProcessorImpl(anInputValue);
    return proc.isEnabled();
}
```

For testing there might be a different implementation of the Processor, so I'd like to avoid the `new` call and in the course of that get rid of the dependency on the implementation.

If my class could just remember an instance of Processor I could inject it via the constructor, but as the Processors are designed to be immutable I need a new one every time.

How would I go about and achieve that with Guice (2.0) ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is some time since I used Guice now, but I remember something called "assisted injection". It allows you to define a factory method where some parameters are supplied and some are injected. Instead of injecting the Processor you inject a processor factory, that has a factory method that takes the `anInputValue` parameter.

I point you to the [javadoc of the FactoryProvider](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/FactoryProvider.html). I believe it should be usable for you.

Comment: Yup, AssistedInject is the best solution.
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject

Comment: Here is a short post I wrote about it. Assisted Injection is a wonderful tool for some problems, and I believe that it's not that well known. Good work spreading the knowledge. http://ripper234.com/p/assisted-injection-in-guice/

Comment: Where can I get the .jar for assisted inject?  It's not available as a download at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/list.

Comment: For anyone else looking, it's available in http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.inject.extensions%22%20AND%20a%3A%22guice-assistedinject%22

Answer (score 11):

You can get the effect you want by injecting a "Provider", which can by asked at runtime to give you a Processor. Providers provide a way to defer the construction of an object until requested.

They're covered in the Guice Docs [here](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-guice&s=google-guice&t=ProviderBindings) and [here](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-guice&s=google-guice&t=InjectingProviders).

The provider will look something like

```
public class ProcessorProvider implements Provider<Processor> {
    public Processor get() {
        // construct and return a Processor
    }
}
```

Since Providers are constructed and injected by Guice, they can themselves have bits injected.

Your code will look something like

```
@Inject
public MyClass(ProcessorProvider processorProvider) {
    this.processorProvider = processorProvider;
}

public boolean myMethod(String anInputValue) {
    return processorProvider.get().isEnabled(anInputValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be what I was looking for. Sometimes you don't see the forest for all the trees.

Comment: And you'll want to bind a DebugProcessorProvider from your debug Modules, but if you've been using Guice, you've probably already figured that out.

Comment: Seeing as the API has now changed to Process.isEnabled(anInputValue) (the same as in my response), why bother include a Provider now? Why not just have a single Processor and skip the Provider completely?

Comment: MrWiggles: Sorry for my first comment. You are right of course. What I failed to recognize here in the example is that the provider does not have any parameters either. @Assisted is the way to go, even though the example is not correct in that regard. I now inject a ProcessorFactory. Changed the accepted answer accordingly.

Comment: Corrected a bug in the example. And agree that @Assisted is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Does your Processor need access to `anInputValue` for its entire lifecycle? If not, could the value be passed in for the method call you're using, something like:

```
@Inject
public MyClass(Processor processor) {
    this.processor = processor;
}

public boolean myMethod(String anInputValue) {
    return processor.isEnabled(anInputValue);
}
```

Comment: The Processor implementations are designed to be immutable, creating them once with all the data they need, then only ask them for stuff.